# Handling browser's back button with jsonp

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I see quite a lot of History plugin for jquery but Im not quite sure which one of them supports JsonP (json with padding)? Do you guys know of a plugin where it can handle the Back button and JsonP requests?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit?  Your question doesn't make much sense at the moment...perhaps some context will help, what *doesn't* work with the back button, or what do you need to handle?

Comment: Hi , sorry if I didnt make myself clear. In my application I have a paginated content. When a user clicks on a page number it will send a request to a remote server, and then update the content. I used JSONP to circumvent the same domain policy of browsers. 

What I would wish to achieve is , say for example a user is in page number 10, and then he suddenly clicks on the back button, the site should display the results from page number 9, and not the previous website / url he was in.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u should add to the document.location the page number like this /articles/pages/#10 with adding to a html href="#10" and you will get navigation with back, also after page load you should parse document.location and refresh page content(send jsonp req for it) for page number in url.